# how to get the mod_strings of the current module in an entrypoint?

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

About the global variable $mod_strings can be read in the [documentation](https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/language-strings/)

> $mod_strings will only contain the strings for the current module

I have problems trying to access the strings of the current module in the context of an entrypoint.

Having this js script

```
function save(records) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("records", JSON.stringify(records));

    fetch("index.php?entryPoint=ImportRecords", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
            // if json.ok
            // - close modal
            // - clean input:file content
            // - alert user?
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error.message));
}
```

In the entry point `$mod_strings` refers to the Home module, and consequently I get the string from the Home module. And I need to get the strings from a custom module

```
<?php

if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

global $mod_strings;

$reduce = array_reduce($mod_strings, function($accumulator, current) {
    // Do something with $mod_strings
});
```

How to get the mod_strings of a specific module in an entry point context?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can get mod_string using the below function in your entry point:

//$language = you can pass different language in which language you want mod_string. By default, it will return in SuiteCRM default language.

```
$current_modData = return_module_language($language, $custom_module_name);
```

may it will help you.